# Do I have to enter my real and true information when making Apple ID account?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, internationalization

Do I have to enter my real and true information when making Apple ID account?
My country is not offered, it is not on the list of countries when I have making an Apple ID account. So, I can not enter my real and correct street and my true  city in which I live. Can I enter false information? Is it allowed or punishable?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that it's punishable if you were to get caught, Apple's not a government branch, so it's not like it would be fraud (I don't know how Apple would find out, anyway). Do you have any relatives or friends in the US or Britain or any of the other eligible countries that would allow top use their address?

That's the best thing to do. You can search here on people that did what you did and then ran into problems when they wanted to switch to their country when it arrived. Your call if the risk of having two accounts outweighs the benefits of having an account today.